# Android UDP hole punching

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, udp

I am trying to make an streaming app and I want to use UDP. I would like the connection to be P2P. So I have a java tcp server running on google cloud, an android phone and my pc. When android connects to tcp server it will create a DatagramSocket on the server that will receive the packet android sends to get the port and ip. Same for the pc. Each client will get the other's client ip and port and each client will get the port that the server received (EG: android sends from port 18000, it will get other's client ip and port and port 18000). Then I close the initial DatagramSocket and open a new one that is bound to the port it gets from server (in our eg 18000). But the connection is never created between the pc and android (android is on 4G and pc on router , so different networks)

```
     socket = new DatagramSocket(Integer.parseInt(po));
```

Here is how I create the P2P datgram socket, where po is 18000 (each client has different po - the android has 18000 and the pc has let's say 45000), I get those port from tcp server and is ok.

```
    public void send() throws NumberFormatException, IOException
{
    //only for testing
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    buffer = "test".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length,InetAddress.getByName(ip),Integer.parseInt(port));
    socket.send(packet);
    
}
```

Here is how i send data from the P2P datagram. The ip is the other's client public ip and the port is the other's client port that is listening.

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while (true) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[64000];
            
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        try {
            socket.receive(packet);
            //acum ca am primit 
            String ana = new String(packet.getData());
            System.err.println("Am primit de la celalalt "+ana);
}
}
```

Here is the thread that listens for incoming packets.
The main problem is that this works but only when the client are on the same network as the server!Even if I both client are on the same netowk , but the server is on a different one, they won't receive anything. Data sent from TCP is 100% correct.

```
                 DatagramPacket packet= new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length, InetAddress.getByName("server_ip"),port_main);
                socket_udp.send(packet);
```

Here is how I send the UDP packet to the server in order to get the port back.

I tried using the same `socket_udp` ,without creating `socket` var again, it failed too.

Comment: Connection failure between pc and phone can be of many reason like firewall, [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), router port forward etc.

Comment: @Liju true,but am I not creating a hole ? I firstly send from each client data to server from different ports (let's say 25000 and 18000). Don't I have those ports opened for udp communcation? Or carrier grade NAT detects this hole and closes it? Wht is strange is that I see the packets sent from each client in Wireshark (on both ends) but I am not receiving them in my app.

Comment: @Liju is hole punching working for every type or NAT or just for some of them?

Comment: Punch hole process can be disturbed with different behaviors of NAT, as NAT behaviors are not standardized. For this process to be successful (1)a NAT should be a [Cone NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Full-cone_NAT) (2)a NAT should not reject unsolicited TCP connection with `RST` packet or ICMP error report, instead it should drop `SYN` packet silently, (3). NAT should support [hairpin translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairpinning). (4)NAT should not scan through packet body to replace all IP addresses.

Comment: Here the absence of hairpin translation (or NAT loop back) is pretty common. In your case at least one of the above reasons must have disrupted your p2p connection.

Comment: @Liju i am just seeing those packets sent in Wireshark not received. So the NAT blocks them yes? If I will try this with both clients on 4g do you think it ll work?

Comment: I can say only possibilities with limited data you provided. Even if you try with both the systems under 4g, I am not sure if your 4g ISP NAT supports loopback. Give it a try anyway.

Comment: @Liju if you think that i missed something that could help you help me please say. And one more problem , even if I bind my android client to the udp port sent by the servs on wireshark it send messages from another port, I think because the one which the phone client is connected to the server is busy , but in fact it is not bcs. I close the connection between server and phone client.

Comment: @Liju just patched this, the ports are the same on both clients. I am just not receiving anything. Should I disable my router firewall and test it?

Comment: @Liju or can i add a rule to the firewall so he can let these udp client connect P2P?

Comment: @Liju they are not  working when they are even on the same netowk with the router firewall of and windows firewall of. I really have no idea why. Wireshark still sees sent data from both clients.